# How to extract page_count for xlsx and txt documents

Tags: java, excel, apache-tika

I wrote a Java application that uses tika to extract the page count metadata.

It works great for docx, pdf, pptx.  However, for xlsx and txt (plain txt) documents, the page count is not in the metadata.  How could I use tika to extract the page count for xlsx and txt documents?

Comment: Hi @jaypas, could you please show what code you've tried?

Comment: What page size do you have in mind? And what font? The number of pages for an Excel file or a Plain Text file depends very very heavily on those two....